# Change format of json output

Tags: ruby, json

The following method gives me:

```
ICD1 = []
def parse_kapitel(node)   
    ICD1 << {von: node.css('~ von_icd_code')[0]['V'],
             bis: node.css('~ bis_icd_code')[0]['V'],
             bezeichnung: node.css('~ bezeichnung')[0]['V']}
end
File.write('Icd1.json', ICD1)
```

an output that looks something like this:

```
[{:von=>"A00", :bis=>"B99", :bezeichnung=>"Bestim.....
```

But I would like an output that looks like this:

```
[{"von":"A00", "bis":"B99", "bezeichnung":"Bestim.....
```

How can I achieve this in an easy ruby way?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Are you asking how to change the way `puts` works with respect to hashes with a symbol key, or you want to achieve such string in the form you presented? I cannot see how json is relevant.

Comment: My problem is that i would like to perform this task with the data: `file_Icd1Codes = File.read('Icd1.json')
Icd1Code.create(JSON.parse(file_Icd1Codes))` And somehow this wont work with the data format i have at the moment! Thanks for your help!

Comment: In my original code i dont have `puts ICD1` instead i save the json to a file `File.write('Icd1.json', ICD1)` ! @sawa i think my problem is that i dont now how to correctly create json with ruby! Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do as below using [`Generating JSON`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html#module-JSON-label-Generating+JSON) :

```
require 'json'

[{ :von=>"A00", :bis=>"B99", :bezeichnung=>"Bestim" }].map(&:to_json)
# => ["{\"von\":\"A00\",\"bis\":\"B99\",\"bezeichnung\":\"Bestim\"}"]
```